# How to get the following isomorphism?

Tags: representation-theory

Here is an example of the paper "Canonical bimodules and dominant dimension":https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303555128_Canonical_bimodules_and_dominant_dimension
[image]

I can get that $B$ is basic and selfinjective. So I get that $B$ is a Forbenius algebra, but I don't know how to check that $(S_1')_{\nu}\cong S'_2$ for any Nakayama automorphism $\nu$ of $B$. Thank you for any help

Comment: use that two nakayama automorphisms are related by inner automorphisms, see proposition 3.3. in chapter IV in the books frobenius algebras I by skowronski yamgata.

Comment: @Mare Actually I don't know how to get a specific Nakayama automrophism of the algebra. Now I know that by the book you say. Thank you.